# For two functions $P(x)$ and $l(x)$ satisfying certain properties which option is correct?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $P(x) = x^n + \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_k x^k$ and $l(x) = x^n + \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b_k x^k$ be two polynomials with real coefficients such that $n \ge 4$ is even and

$a_{n-1} < b_{n-1}$.

Let $f(x)$  be a function such that  $P(x) \le f(x) \le l(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Then which among the following is true ?

(a) $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$

(b) $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

(c) $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

(d) $f$ is continuous at least one  point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

So, I know option (a) is clearly false using graph of various functions I can construct an unbounded function,

For option (c) again I can choose $P(x)$ and $l(x)$ so that my $f(x)$ is above $x$ axis.

I am mainly confused about (b) and (d), I think the function must be continous at least once, but I have no idea how to prove it .

Can anyone help me here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No such $f$ exists. Consider $l-P$, which is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Since it's degree is odd, it's limit in $+\infty$ is opposite to it's limit in $-\infty$. Hence, $l-P$ changes sign, which means at some point $l(x) < P(x)$.

If the question were $\min(P(x),l(x)) \leq f(x) \leq \max(P(x),l(x))$, the correct answer would be (d), since at at least one point we get $l(a)-P(a)=0$, and hence $l(a)=P(a)$. Therefore, $f(a)=l(a)=P(a)$, and by the sandwich theorem, $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was just confused by the details of $a_n$ and $b_n$ that were given in the questions.

Comment: The important thing is that $a_{n-1} \neq b_{n-1}$, which makes it so that $l-P$ is a polynomial of odd degree.